# How to change the default location of the screen shot?

Tags: screen-capture

I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to screen shot.

But you know the default place of the screen shot is Desktop.

So, how can I change the default location? I want to the location to be a custom document folder, not desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this with a bash command.

1. Open the Terminal Application and enter this:

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/`

And change '~/Pictures/' to your preferred Location. For example, if you have in your User folder a Folder named 'screenshots' then change the command to:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/screenshots/
```

2. Press enter to execute command
3. Next: Enter: `killall SystemUIServer`to reinitialize the 'SystemUIServer' to adopt changes

For more information check out: [oxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/01/26/change-the-screenshot-save-file-location-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me in macOS Mojave, even with the `killall` invocation.

Comment: in Mojave you don't need this any more you can change the save location now from the GUI [see this tutorial](https://www.howtoisolve.com/how-to-customize-or-change-screenshot-save-location-macos-mojave-on-mac/)